# SQL Update to the SUM of its joined values

Tags: sql, sum, sql-update

I'm trying to update a field in the database to the sum of its joined values:

```
UPDATE P
SET extrasPrice = SUM(E.price)
FROM dbo.BookingPitchExtras AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.BookingPitches AS P ON E.pitchID = P.ID
    AND P.bookingID = 1
WHERE E.[required] = 1
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
"An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to update *some* dbo.BookingPitches records with a sum of all the corresponding dbo.BookingPitcheExtras records `price` column?

Comment: You need to specify which field you want to group on if you are going to use `SUM`.

Comment: This statement doesn't make any sense. What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE 
     p
SET 
     p.extrasPrice = t.sumPrice
FROM 
     BookingPitches AS p
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
             PitchID, 
             SUM(Price) AS sumPrice
        FROM 
             BookingPitchExtras
        WHERE 
             [required] = 1
        GROUP BY 
             PitchID 
    ) t
ON 
     t.PitchID = p.ID
WHERE 
     p.bookingID = 1;
```

Comment: I used this syntax today as a guide in shaping my update statement, worked like a charm. As a side note, make sure to use the alias values exactly as you see them here. I didn't at first and spent a little while trying to figure out my issue.

Answer (score 11):

An alternate to the above solutions is using Aliases for Tables:

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.extrasPrice = (SELECT SUM(T2.Price) FROM BookingPitchExtras T2 WHERE T2.pitchID = T1.ID)
FROM BookingPitches T1;
```

Comment: i have to change the variable like `UPDATE BookingPitches SET extrasPrice = `

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and found that I could solve it with a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (available in SQL 2005 or later):

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT PitchID, SUM(Price) somePrice
    FROM BookingPitchExtras
    WHERE [required] = 1 
    GROUP BY PitchID)
UPDATE p SET p.extrasPrice=cte.SomePrice
FROM BookingPitches p INNER JOIN cte ON p.ID=cte.PitchID
WHERE p.BookingID=1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid error. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90477). Following (and others suggested below) are the ways to achieve this:-

```
UPDATE P 
SET extrasPrice = t.TotalPrice
FROM BookingPitches AS P INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT
    PitchID,
    SUM(Price) TotalPrice
  FROM
     BookingPitchExtras
  GROUP BY PitchID
  ) t
ON t.PitchID = p.ID
```

Comment: @Ashish Gupta - Looks a lot like my query...hmm

Comment: ooops...sorry..Want me to delete the answer? I didnot load the answer when I was writing the query and was reading that article.

Comment: No that is fine I just thought it was odd that we even used the same temp storage t, and the query was quite almost exactly the same.  2 answers are better then 1.

Comment: JonH, I will learn to load the answers while I am writing answers. Sorry again. Didn't mean that. I edited my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this :

```
UPDATE P
SET ExtrasPrice = E.TotalPrice
FROM dbo.BookingPitches AS P
INNER JOIN (SELECT BPE.PitchID, Sum(BPE.Price) AS TotalPrice
    FROM BookingPitchExtras AS BPE
    WHERE BPE.[Required] = 1
    GROUP BY BPE.PitchID) AS E ON P.ID = E.PitchID
WHERE P.BookingID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With postgres, I had to adjust the solution with this to work for me:

```
UPDATE BookingPitches AS p
SET extrasPrice = t.sumPrice
FROM 
    (
        SELECT PitchID, SUM(Price) sumPrice
        FROM BookingPitchExtras
        WHERE [required] = 1
        GROUP BY PitchID 
    ) t
WHERE t.PitchID = p.ID AND p.bookingID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query similar to the below.

```
UPDATE P
SET extrasPrice = sub.TotalPrice from
BookingPitches p
inner join 
(Select PitchID, Sum(Price) TotalPrice
    from  dbo.BookingPitchExtras
    Where [Required] = 1
    Group by Pitchid
) as Sub
on p.Id = e.PitchId 
where p.BookingId = 1
```