# SQL: SUM and Update query error,

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update my riders total ucipoints by following an example, with some small modifications, but I just get an error from it.

**example**

```
UPDATE P 
SET extrasPrice = t.TotalPrice
FROM BookingPitches AS P INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT
    PitchID,
    SUM(Price) TotalPrice
  FROM
     BookingPitchExtras
  GROUP BY PitchID
  ) t
ON t.PitchID = p.ID
```

I got the code from this answer:
[SQL Update to the SUM of its joined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502032/sql-update-to-the-sum-of-its-joined-values)

**My code looks like this:**

```
 UPDATE P
SET ucipoeng = t.TotalPoints
FROM rytterlagsesong AS P INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT
    rytterid,
    SUM(poeng) AS TotalPoints
  FROM
     t_ucipoeng
WHERE year(dato)='2016'
  GROUP BY rytterid
  ) t
ON t.rytterid = P.rytterid AND t.sesong='2016'
```

I get the error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM rytterlagsesong AS P INNER JOIN ( SELECT rytterid, SUM(ucip' at line 3

Can someone help me find the error?

DB Structure:
rytterlagsesong: rytterid - ucipoeng - sesong
t_ucipoeng: rytterid - dato - poeng

So I want to sum the points (poeng) of all races in 2016 (dato=date) for a rider
And update that riders totalpoint (ucipoeng) for this season (sesong)

Comment: this is t-sql syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update / join` syntax is different per database.  For `mysql`, use this:

```
UPDATE rytterlagsesong r
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT rytterid, SUM(poeng) AS TotalPoints
        FROM t_ucipoeng
        WHERE year(dato)='2016'
        GROUP BY rytterid
    ) t ON t.rytterid = r.rytterid AND t.sesong='2016'
SET r.ucipoeng = t.TotalPoints
```

Comment: worked perfect! Found one small typo, that was my fault, t.sesong should be r.sesong (its wrong in my original post too)