# Updating column in table with sum of another table

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I'm relatively new to SQL and have been unable to solve the following issue.

In brief, I have two tables. We can call the first table `people`:

```
name
--------
Margaret
Jim
Lola
```

The second is a list of `expenses` of different types associated with the different entities:

```
name     | type     | amount
---------+----------+-------
Margaret | personal |    100
Jim      | business |     50
Lola     | business |    275
Margaret | business |     75
Lola     | personal |     10
Margaret | business |    150
Lola     | personal |     50
Jim      | business |    150
```

I'd like to add two columns to the first table, so that it looks like this:

```
name     | personal_expenses | business_expenses
---------+-------------------+------------------
Margaret |               100 |               275
Jim      |                 0 |               200
Lola     |               275 |                60
```

Initially, my hope was that I would be able to accomplish this with the following query, after adding the `personal_expenses` and `business_expenses` columns:

```
UPDATE people
SET personal_expenses = (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM expenses
    GROUP BY name
);
```

I have also tried:

```
UPDATE people
SET personal_expenses = (
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM expenses
    WHERE expenses.name = people.name
);
```

but likewise to no avail.

I've looked at [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009927/aggregate-function-in-an-sql-update-query) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b) to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502032/sql-update-to-the-sum-of-its-joined-values), but when I attempt--admittedly, perhaps incorrectly--to replicate them in `sqlite3` I get (very uninformative) syntax errors.

What is the proper way to achieve this disaggregated sum in `sqlite3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close! You forgot one more condition in your `WHERE` clause.  Also the sums in your example are not correct based on the example data you gave in the `expense` table

```
ALTER TABLE `people` ADD COLUMN `personal_expense` INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE `people` ADD COLUMN `business_expense` INTEGER;

UPDATE people
SET personal_expense = (
      SELECT SUM(amount)
      FROM expenses
      WHERE expenses.type = 'personal'
        AND expenses.name = people.name ),

    business_expense = (
      SELECT SUM(amount)
      FROM expenses
      WHERE expenses.type = 'business'
        AND expenses.name = people.name )
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. The issue I'm confronting now is that the actual database I'm working with has ~50,000 rows in the `expenses` table and ~10,000 in the `people` table. I don't know how the `sqlite3` backend works, but my sense is that this is fairly inefficient (bringing the entire table into memory once for each row). It's very fast to `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM people JOIN expenses ON people.name = expenses.name GROUP BY expenses.name;` this creates a single column table with the right number of rows. Isn't there some way to just add this column onto the original `people` table?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are asking for.
You already have columns in the `people` table for the expenses called `personal_expense` and `business_expense`.
In order to speed up the `UPDATE` query above, you can create an index on expenses.name + expenses.type

Comment: Great, thanks--again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  Give my answer an up-vote if you like it ;)