# Updating column in sqlite table ... problems with groupby?

Tags: sql, sqlite, julia

```
-- Adding column Main Table
ALTER TABLE MainTable ADD COLUMN new_col REAL;


;WITH AddColTable AS (
       SELECT other_id, COUNT(main_id) as new_col
       FROM MainTable 
       GROUP BY other_id
)

UPDATE MainTable
SET new_col = (
    FROM MainTable
    INNER JOIN AddColTable
    ON MainTable.main_id == AddColTable.main_id
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around why this statement doesn't work.
I have tried many different combinations of this using JOIN - in some cases even 3 nested levels unfortunately.

Is there an obvious way to fix this statement?

The goal is similar to others stated elsewhere, such as here: [Updating column in table with sum of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120610/updating-column-in-table-with-sum-of-another-table)

However, the important difference seems to be operating on the table itself instead of adding a column based on another table.

I assumed this could be solved by using the `with tbl as ()` statement, but it still doesn't work.

### Example displaying the problem (in julia)

```
using SQLite, DBInterface, DataFrames
cxn = SQLite.DB(":memory:")

DBInterface.execute(cxn,"""
    CREATE TABLE
    MainTable(main_id INTEGER,
              other_id INTEGER)""")

DBInterface.execute(cxn,"""
    INSERT INTO MainTable
    VALUES (1,  13),
           (2, 213),
           (3,  13),
           (4, 342),
           (5, 213),
           (6, 213),
           (7,   4)""")

# Try to add new column which shows aggregate information about 'other_id'
DBInterface.execute(cxn, "
    -- Adding column Main Table
    ALTER TABLE MainTable ADD COLUMN new_col REAL;

    ;WITH AddColTable AS (
           SELECT other_id, COUNT(main_id) as new_col
           FROM MainTable 
           GROUP BY other_id
    )

    UPDATE MainTable
    SET new_col = (
        FROM MainTable
        INNER JOIN AddColTable
        ON MainTable.main_id == AddColTable.main_id)")


##### Show what happened #####

# Initial table
sql = "SELECT * FROM MainTable"
df = DataFrame(DBInterface.execute(cxn, sql))
println("Starting Table:\n $(df) \n\n")

# The aggregate information table, which 
#   should have a column added (joined) with the initial table
sql = "SELECT other_id, COUNT(main_id) as new_col
       FROM MainTable 
       GROUP BY other_id"
df = DataFrame(DBInterface.execute(cxn, sql))
println("Aggregate Information Table:\n $(df) \n\n")

# The actual table change using 'ALTER TABLE .. UPDATE .. SET'
sql = "SELECT * FROM MainTable"
df = DataFrame(DBInterface.execute(cxn, sql))
println("Main Table After Update:\n $(df) \n\n")

# The expected table
sql = "SELECT main_id, A.other_id, actual_new_col as new_col
       FROM MainTable
       INNER JOIN (
            SELECT other_id, COUNT(main_id) as actual_new_col
            FROM MainTable 
            GROUP BY other_id) AS A
       ON MainTable.other_id == A.other_id"
df = DataFrame(DBInterface.execute(cxn, sql))
println("*EXPECTED* Main Table After Update:\n $(df) \n\n")

DBInterface.close!(cxn)
```

This gives the following output:

### Simple output vs expectation

#### Starting Table

```
 7×3 DataFrame
 Row │ main_id  other_id  new_col
     │ Int64    Int64     Missing
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │       1        13  missing
   2 │       2       213  missing
   3 │       3        13  missing
   4 │       4       342  missing
   5 │       5       213  missing
   6 │       6       213  missing
   7 │       7         4  missing
```

#### Aggregate Information Table

```
 4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ other_id  new_col
     │ Int64     Int64
─────┼───────────────────
   1 │        4        1
   2 │       13        2
   3 │      213        3
   4 │      342        1
```

#### Main Table After Update

```
 7×3 DataFrame
 Row │ main_id  other_id  new_col
     │ Int64    Int64     Missing
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │       1        13  missing
   2 │       2       213  missing
   3 │       3        13  missing
   4 │       4       342  missing
   5 │       5       213  missing
   6 │       6       213  missing
   7 │       7         4  missing
```

#### *EXPECTED* Main Table After Update

```
 7×3 DataFrame
 Row │ main_id  other_id  new_col
     │ Int64    Int64     Int64
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │       1        13        2
   2 │       2       213        3
   3 │       3        13        2
   4 │       4       342        1
   5 │       5       213        3
   6 │       6       213        3
   7 │       7         4        1
```

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: the version in 3.38.2 @forpas

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support an explicit join of the updated table in the `UPDATE` statement.

Since version 3.33.0+ SQLite supports the [`UPDATE...FROM...`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax:

```
WITH AddColTable AS (
  SELECT other_id, COUNT(main_id) as new_col
  FROM MainTable 
  GROUP BY other_id
)
UPDATE MainTable AS m
SET new_col = a.new_col
FROM AddColTable AS a
WHERE a.other_id = m.other_id;
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2aa43d/3).

For older versions the solution is a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE MainTable AS m1
SET new_col = (
  SELECT COUNT(m2.main_id) 
  FROM MainTable AS m2 
  WHERE m2.other_id = m1.other_id
);
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2aa43d/4).

Comment: For some reason, neither of these are working - if you place either of these statements into the julia example I provided above, both still provide 'missing' as the column values.

Comment: @chase you can see in the 2 demo links I provide in my answer that both queries work fine. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I figured it out - the `ALTER TABLE` statement needed to be ran individually in a separate `DBInterface.execute()` call.
Thank you!